# What is the Sanskrit name for Australia?

Tags: vedas, puranas, name

Is there a recorded name for Australia in any of the sacred texts? A Google search shows that it is said that "Mahalamka" or "Mahalanka" is the name for Australia. I am not sure though.

Comment: If you are asking for Sankalpa purpose then this article might help -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaksadvipa

Comment: Also useful may be [this](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-purana-english/d/doc216086.html) excerpt from the Brahma Purana, although it doesn't include Australia.